# Connect local asp dotnet core app to Azure SQL using managed identity with VSCode

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-sql-database

I have a web app hosted in azure, it has system managed identity turned on, I also have an Azure SQL Database which I have enabled access for that identity on.

When it's running in the cloud it works fine and it can query the database. However, when running locally, I want to be able to debug against the cloud database, but I want to use the same connection style (as we have disabled SQL logins)

I am running dotnet core 3.0 on macOS and using VSCode for the IDE... is there any way to set environment variables or something to allow my local instance to connect? I am aware that you can do it on windows and full blown Visual Studio by logging into VS.

I have tried these environment variables, but it doesn't seem to work (using the same ids as the app in azure is using)

```
"IdentityObjectId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"IdentityTenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working now, here's how, for anyone that comes across this post later.

Background to my configuration setup:
I added an azure AD user as an admin, and gave that user access to azure sql.

```
azureaduser=$(az ad user list --filter "userPrincipalName eq 'MYUSERNAME'" --query [].objectId --output tsv)
az sql server ad-admin create --resource-group MYRESOURCEGROUP --server-name MYSQLSERVER.database.windows.net --display-name ADMIN --object-id $azureaduser
```

I created an azure AD group and added that user to the group. I also added the service principle (managed identity) for the azure webapp to that group as well.

```
groupid=$(az ad group create --display-name sqlAccessGroup --mail-nickname sqlAccessGroup --query objectId --output tsv)
msiobjectid=$(az webapp identity show --resource-group RESOURCEGROUPNAME --name MYWEBAPPNAME --query principalId --output tsv)
az ad group member add --group $groupid --member-id $msiobjectid
```

Logging in as this admin user, I am able to connect to the database via Azure Cloud Shell and run sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S MYSERVER.database.windows.net -d MYDATABASE -U "MYUSER@MYSUBSCRIPTION.onmicrosoft.com" -P "MYPASSWORD" -G -l 30
```

**Note: I could already access this database with SQL Authentication, but you can't add AD groups/users to the database unless you are logged in with an Azure AD Account (hence the creation of the admin account earlier)**

```
CREATE USER [sqlAccessGroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [sqlAccessGroup];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [sqlAccessGroup];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [sqlAccessGroup];
GO
```

I also have Allow Azure Services Access turned off on my Azure SQL so I had to add the web app's outbound IP to the firewall.... and speaking of firewalls, make sure your local machine's IP is in there too.

The real solution to this issue for me was running "az login" in the terminal of VS Code, which seems to create an "Identity Context" that allows me to use my "Admin User" from above to login, and thus have access to the database. It's not *Exactly* like running from the web app itself, but it's close enough and doesn't require a second connection string or SQL Authentication to be enabled.

Comment: You can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to do the "wait 2 days thing" there.